# dsolve generating inconsistent outputs

Tags: matlab, dsolve

I've been playing with this for awhile, Can anyone explain why I get different answers from Code1 and Code2? What is it about the actual script of 'dsolve()' that makes the output of the 2 codes different? Could the output be the same if I just used different syntax (ie ',;".')?

```
%Code1:

syms Qua t Area height

rate_in = 3*Qua*(sin(t))^2; 
delta_Vol = dsolve('DAreaY = rate_in - Qua');
delta_Height= dsolve('Dheight = ((rate_in - Qua)/Area)', 'height(0) = 0');
 subfnc1 = subs(rate_in, {Qua}, {450});
fnc1 = subs(delta_Height, {'rate_in'}, {subfnc1});
fnc1 = subs(fnc1, {Area, Qua}, {1250,450});
fnc_main = matlabFunction(fnc1);
fnc_main(0:10)';

%Code2:

syms Qua t Area height

rate_in = 3*Qua*(sin(t))^2; 
delta_Vol = dsolve('DAreaY = 3*Qua*(sin(t))^2 - Qua');
delta_Height= dsolve('Dheight = ((3*Qua*(sin(t))^2 - Qua)/Area)', 'height(0) = 0');
fnc1 = subs(delta_Height, {Area, Qua}, {1250,450});
fnc_main = matlabFunction(fnc1);
fnc_main(0:10)';
```

what is it about the dsolved function that I don't understand?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem might be that you're passing strings to `dsolve` rather than symbolic expressions. This means that in the first case `rate_i` might be interpreted as a constant, rather than a function of `t`.

Here's what you're probably trying to do: defining `Dheight` as a `sym` as well, and telling `dsolve` what to do using `sym`s:

```
%Code1:

clear Qua t Area height Dheight
syms Qua t Area height(t) Dheight

Dheight = diff(height);
rate_in = 3*Qua*(sin(t))^2; 
delta_Height= dsolve(Dheight == ((rate_in - Qua)/Area), height(0) == 0);
subfnc1 = subs(rate_in, {Qua}, {450});
fnc1 = subs(delta_Height, {'rate_in'}, {subfnc1});
fnc1 = subs(fnc1, {Area, Qua}, {1250,450});
fnc_main = matlabFunction(fnc1)

%Code2:

clear Qua t Area height Dheight
syms Qua t Area height(t) Dheight

Dheight = diff(height);
rate_in = 3*Qua*(sin(t))^2; 
delta_Height= dsolve(Dheight == ((3*Qua*(sin(t))^2 - Qua)/Area), height(0) == 0);
fnc1 = subs(delta_Height, {Area, Qua}, {1250,450});
fnc_main = matlabFunction(fnc1)
```

Changes to your version:

- I removed `delta_Vol` since it wasn't used and contained an unclear reference to `(D)AreaY`
- I changed in `dsolve` from string to symbolic expression, in the mean time `=` had to be changed to `==`
- I defined `DHeight` as `diff(Height)`, which implies that `height` has to be declared as `height(t)`. This also allows us to define the initial condition as `height(0)==0`, otherwise we'd have needed to keep this a string: `'height(0)=0'`.

Now both versions return the same solution:

```
fnc_main = 

    @(t)t.*(9.0./5.0e1)-sin(t.*2.0).*(2.7e1./1.0e2)
```

I suggest checking on paper whether this solution, or its symbolic predecessor,

```
delta_Height =

(Qua*(2*t - 3*sin(2*t)))/(4*Area)
```

is indeed a solution to your differential equation.

Comment: thank you, this is another perspective/route in how I can choose to code, that the book/instructor does not offer. Thank you as I assumed dsolve() only accepted strings, but now I see how i can insert symbolic arguments. I also never knew I could have a variable declaration, like  height explicitly defined in terms of another variable, like (t).